# Keymando 'Reload' Command

Tags: reload, keymando

I have never gotten this 'reload' command to work ... regardless of the mapping ...

currently using ...

```
map "<Ctrl-Cmd-r>" { reload } # not reloading either
```

Could you provide another example?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using, using a mnemonic with the growl plugin:

```
def reload_configuration
  lambda{ growl("Configuration reloaded successfully") if reload}
end

map "<Cmd-y>" do 
  input("rel" => reload_configuration)
end
```

Comment: sorry, but still does not work ... i am beginning to suspect that me being on a MacBook Air is making a defference. Opinion? Comments?

Comment: What version of growl are you running?  I just talked to someone who said it quick working for them when they upgraded to 1.3.